Swift6 concurrency and NSBundleResourceRequest
I am struggling to understand why my code doesn't work in Swift6 mode.
Here is a minimalistic example:
final actor ODRRequest {
    let request = NSBundleResourceRequest(tags: ["bla"])

    func startRequest() {
        Task {[unowned self] in
            let available = await request.conditionallyBeginAccessingResources()
            if available {
                updateState(.available)
            }
        }
    }
}

This fails telling me that "Sending actor-isolated value of type 'NSBundleResourceRequest' with later accesses to nonisolated context risks causing data races".
At the same time, this works without issues:
private func startRequest() {
    request.conditionallyBeginAccessingResources {[unowned self]  available in
        Task {
            if available {
                await updateState(.available)
            }
        }
    }
}

Can anyone explain to me why does compiler complain about the first implementation but does not complain about the second? These functions are supposed to be identical.

NSBundleRequest is a non-Sendable class. request is a class instance, i.e. a reference to a mutable instance. You must not share such an instance across the isolation boundary, because what if this isolation region mutates the property at the same time that the other isolation region mutates it?

@matt I get it, but what is the difference between async await and completion implementations? Surely the same argument applies to both. By the time my completion is called, request could get modified.
On a separate note – do you have any idea how I can resolve this? In reality my request is a constant which gets initialised in init and I only call conditionallyBeginAccessingResources, beginAccessingResource and endAccessingResource...

Oh, yes I see the question. The difference is that the completion implementation, not being async/await, doesn't get any protection assistance from the compiler!

Ok, so how could I resolve this? I would really love to implement Swift6 across my app, but this issue prevents me from doing this. I am more than happy to define request as immutable, but looks like there is no way to do this as it is a class. At the same time, I must store it, as On Demand Resources get deallocated if no request references them (meaning my request must live outside of function scope)...

I think you can solve it just by capturing [request] in your Task.

wow wow wow. Yes it works :D Gonna read more about what it actually means

But I have another solution, which I will post in a moment...

Capturing works, but I do not understand why. I always thought that capturing a variable prevents it from getting deallocated (and this is more or less the info I find online now as well). However, if it was just that then it shouldn't work as modifying request outside was still possible. So how does capturing a request in the Task prevents the race condition?

I think you can do what you're trying to do — i.e., move your request and the methods that talk to it off into a single instance — by using a simple class instead of an actor; here's a sketch:
final class ODRRequest {
    var request: NSBundleResourceRequest?

    func startRequest() async {
        let request = NSBundleResourceRequest(tags: ["bla"])
        if await request.conditionallyBeginAccessingResources() {
            // do stuff
        }
        self.request = request
    }

    func beginAccessing() async throws {
        try await request?.beginAccessingResources()
        /// do stuff if we get here
    }

    func stopAccessing() {
        request?.endAccessingResources()
        request = nil
    }
}

That compiles on my machine and I don't think I'm cheating the compiler in some way. Note the use of an Optional; that's how I always do bundle resource requests, so that I can create the request when I'm ready to start using it, and release the request when I'm finished with it. (Either that or I hold my requests in a mutable dictionary, keyed by tags, but it amounts to the same thing.)

I tried this, but I couldn't call the startRequest from init (where I set my NSBundleResourceRequest). If I wrap it in task, I get "Task-isolated value of type '() async -> ()' passed as a strongly transferred parameter; later accesses could race"

Well, there was nothing about calling startRequest from init in your question, and I don't see why it's necessary; the way I present here seems perfectly viable.
